# Discussion : Low quality answers review comment applied question

Tags: discussion, bug

I have recently checked some of the low-quality answer review applied to question.

It happened to me two times. Recently I have checked it happened @sv3n also.

[”Undefined offset: 4” when reindexing “Search indexer”](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/249335/undefined-offset-4-when-reindexing-search-indexer)

Any idea on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's caused by **an answer** that was converted into the comment by a mod.

---

The most plausible chronology:

1. Simonk (a new user with only 1 rep who cannot post a comment) posted an answer

   > Got the same problem... Anyone have a solution?
2. Alexey Giryayev commented on the answer

   > What was the name on your extension?
3. Meanwhile, the answer got flagged (either manually/automatically) as "Not an answer"/"Very low quality post" and entered "Low Quality Post Review" queue
4. [From the review](https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/140744), sv3n recommended a deletion with the standard "I’m having this problem, too" reason.
5. Before reaching the consensus, a mod *converted the post into a comment* on the question. Because of that, the underlying comments were also migrated to the question.

Comment: That said, I flagged sv3n's comment as "no longer needed", so if the review comment is no longer there, don't be confused :)

Comment: Thanks for providing detail.